# Using jqplot on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jqplot, jsdom

I am looking to create graphs on a server, that were perviously done in the browser (for code reuse) and am proposing a node  based server. It would seem that jqplot would work (there are node modules) but have not been able to confirm output. There is scant google results pertaining to node, jsdom and jqplot Here is code:

```
    var jsdom = require('jsdom');
//var html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM('<html><body><div id="save"><div id="chartdiv"></div></div></body></html>', {
    features: {
      FetchExternalResources : ['img']
     }
});
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
var domtoimage = require('dom-to-image');
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
//var $ = jQuery = require('./jquery-1.11.1.min.js')(window);
var jqplot = require("jqplot");

$.jqplot( 'chartdiv', [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
console.log('inner: '+$('#chartdiv').html())
```

The console.log prints a blank.
1. Can someone confirm / improve code? 
2. Is there a way to either save what the jsdom image would look like to a file or display it in some way?